# Are there any tools which specifically measure useful code coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, code-coverage

It is possible, albeit counterproductive, to write a unit test which executes some code, and asserts truth. This is a deliberately extreme, and simplified example - I'm sure most people have come across tests which execute code without actually making use of it.

Are there any code coverage tools which assess whether code covered is actually used as part of the assertions of the test?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170297/code-covered-vs-code-tested

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to *prevent* rather than detect this? (Reviews, Educate)

Comment: @Gishu yes, but on a complex codebase, where you were introducing tests, a reviewer stands very little chance of spotting this problem - and hence can't trigger education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want in essence is to compute the intersection between the covered code, and a  [backward code slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing) (minus the unit test itself) on the assertion in the covered test.

If that intersection is empty, the assertion doesn't test any part of the application.

Most code coverage tools don't compute slices, so I'd guess the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: and even then, I suppose if I understand it right, it would only tell you that some extra code was covered rather than the code you intended was covered.

Comment: It would tell that *some* application code was covered, as evidende by the code that fed values to the assertions.  There would be no way for it to tell you that the "intended" code was covered; it obviously can't read your mind.

Comment: That's what I thought. I suppose this is where TDD practices might help in that you write test => red => write code => green. Then you feel that the code you have been written must have been tested, but again once you go beyond that cycle you could add/remove other code and make the tests pass and you might once more have uncovered code. Your tests are only specifying intent of what you want the code to do rather than how it goes about it  - a tricky one and an approach that can led to brittle tests.

Comment: Intent is not important, if you have a visual tool which can display which code is covered by an Assert statement. I've recently been using DotCover, which has led my thinking in this direction. This could also be useful to indicate orthogonality of tests - where code is covered by multiple assert statements.

Comment: But an assert may not actually cover code - it may be testing a mock expectation or reading a simple property that have been prepared by some previous code. I tend to follow the arrange/act/assert pattern where my 'asserts' are testing that my 'actions' did what I want depending on what I set up in the 'arrange' - sometimes the act/assert become one but this is only for simple tests. You may try to do coverage by test but it would be hard to distinguish code covered by test arrangement (unless in some test setup that can be tracked) and that done by the action and the testing of asserts.

Comment: @penguat: the test executes some code A.  The asserts tests the results of some code B.  There is no gaurantee that B has anything to do with the actual application code (it is easy to write stupid test: "Assert True").  There's no gaurantee the A has anything to do with the application code.  (Here's my unit test, the empty block "{ }").  What you want to know is that that what gets exercised, A ("covered"), has a nonempty interesection with the application code, and that what the assertion checks, B ("backward slice") has a nonempty intersection, and that A interesect B is noonempty.

Comment: @Ira I see, yes. I was including the test itself in the covered code.

Comment: @Shaun I see that mock expectations might be complicated. I also follow that pattern, and I believe I understand it. I am using DotCover, which does indeed identify which test executes a given line of code.

Comment: The tool which comes closest to a useable implementation of this seems to be NCrunch - change a line of code and instantly see if it breaks anything.

Answer (score 0):

You would need some kind of dependency analysis, i.e. to find out which statements the assertion depends on. Then this would have to be cross-checked with the coverage. CodeSurfer is one commercial tool that does dependency analysis for C.

Comment: You could say so. Whether certain code was used as port of the assertion is dependency analysis. Whether certain code was executed by a test is coverage collection. I think your problem is the combination of these two. For easy coverage collection for C, you can always use gcov profiler from gcc suite.

Comment: There have been other SO questions regarding coverage per test but this would require you to run each test and compare coverage - but again it would only tell you that something was covered not that the intended bit of code was actually covered. A dangerous mindset, I think, as I believe, after a few years of TDDing, tests should specify intent of what the code does rather then how it goes about it - which can happen when you over analyse the coverage results.

Answer (score 0):

Once again, I'd just investigate why this is happening ? Tests added just for the sake of increasing coverage numbers often are a symptom of a more serious cause. Educating everyone instead of picking out specific offenders usually works out better.

For identifying mistakes that have already been made: You can use a static code analysis tool that checks that

- each test has atleast ONE assert. Of course this can also be defeated by rogue asserts.
- there are no unused return values.

I saw the first one in something called TestLint from RoyOsherove and the second one I can think of Parasoft or similar.
Still this isn't a foolproof method and will sink significant time poring through the SCA reported issues. But that's the best I can think of.

Comment: I don't have any evidence that this is happening - I only suspect that it is, where I am working. I deliberately asked this in a language/toolchain agnostic way, as I am more interested in whether it has been done than in using it. Tests are added for coverage purposes due to faulty monitoring in this company - but I suspect that is very common.