# Why does coverage.py not report a for loop where the body is not skipped when running it with --branch?

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

Consider the following example file `test.py`:

```py
def fun(l):
    for i in l:
        a = 1
    print(a)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun([1])
```

Testing branch coverage with

```bash
coverage erase; coverage run --branch test.py ; coverage html
```

There are no complains about the for loop although it is not tested with an empty list.
If it was the program would crash with "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment".
Since I have asked [coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.2.1/) for branch coverage instead of statement coverage I would expect this to be reported. Why does coverage not report this?

[image: screenshot of HTML report created by coverage]

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Code covered" vs. "Code tested"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170297/code-covered-vs-code-tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps to understand [how branch coverage works](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/branch.html#how-it-works):

> When measuring branches, `coverage.py` collects pairs of line numbers, a source and destination for each transition from one line to another. Static analysis of the source provides a list of possible transitions. Comparing the measured to the possible indicates missing branches.

```
1| def fun(l):
2|     for i in l:
3|         a = 1
4|     print(a)
```

There are two branches here:

- L2 can proceed to L3
- L2 can jump to L4

The `fun([1])` call in the test actually fully covers both branches. On the first iteration of the loop, we have line 2->3, and on the final iteration, we have jump 2->4.

Remember that 100% coverage does not imply the code actually *works* in all cases, it just means that all those lines and branches have been *visited* during the test suite.

If you modify this code so that only one of the branches of the `for` gets visited, you will see a partial cover highlighted on L3:

[image]

Comment: and when I put an `assert False` into the loop body then I get the warning I expected because then it does not make the transition from line 2 to 4. Makes sense. Thank you for your helpful answer.